# Using ggplot2 to plot multiple lines of different lengths

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have a 2228 by 2 data.frame that looks something like this:

```
> head(diffSums, 10)
                               nTranscripts        Library
D6_NoSort_2250b_ATTATACGCCCC          63963   NoSort_2250b
D6_EcadSort_6000b_CCACACCCAGCC       193050 EcadSort_6000b
D6_EcadSort_2250b_CCGATGATTAGC        77631 EcadSort_2250b
D6_EcadSort_2250b_TGTCTGCTTTAG       106599 EcadSort_2250b
D6_EcadSort_2250b_TTCACAAGTTTC        88775 EcadSort_2250b
D6_EcadSort_6000b_CCATATCCAGCT        97861 EcadSort_6000b
D6_EcadSort_6000b_CAACGACTTAGG        91813 EcadSort_6000b
D6_EcadSort_2250b_AGTGAACAGGCG        80503 NoSort_2250b
D6_EcadSort_2250b_AAGCGGCTGCGC        93326 EcadSort_2250b
D6_EcadSort_2250b_CGTTTCACTTCG        72013 NoSort_2250b
```

where the number of entries per `diffSums$Library` vary:

```
> table(diffSums$Library)

  EcadSort_2250b EcadSort_2250x8b   EcadSort_6000b EcadSort_6000x3b     NoSort_2250b  NoSort_2250x23b   NoSort_2250x8b     NoSort_6000b   NoSort_6000x3b 
             136              321              131              422              269               72              452              192              233
```

I'd like to plot a line for each library on the same plot using ggplot2. I am able to accomplish this by manually grep'n out each library and plotting:

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_line(data=diffSums[grep("EcadSort_6000x3b", rownames(diffSums)),], aes(x=seq(as.vector(table(diffSums$Library))[4]), y=sort(nTranscripts, decreasing=TRUE)), color='green') +
  geom_line(data=diffSums[grep("NoSort_2250b", rownames(diffSums)),], aes(x=seq(as.vector(table(diffSums$Library))[5]), y=sort(nTranscripts, decreasing=TRUE)), color='blue')
```

... but I know there must be an easier way! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's the structure of the data that you want to plot? the 'lib' column of diffSums is missing in the sample data you've included above. Also, what's colSums.diff. in this case? It would be easier to help if you include sample data and a clear explanation of what you would like plotted.

Comment: @shreyasgm Sorry! `lib` == `Library`. Code is updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's still not possible to reproduce the graph that you generated using the data and code provided, but I think this is what you're looking for:

```
library(dplyr)

diffSums <- diffSums %>%
    group_by(Library) %>%
    arrange(-nTranscripts) %>%
    mutate(numLib = seq_len(n()))

ggplot(diffSums, aes(numLib,nTranscripts,colour = Library)) + geom_line()
```

[image]